# JIRA python for JIRA REST API: how to return keys of all child issues for a single parent issue given the parent's key?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I have seen multiple answers for how to return the key of the parent of a given issue, but is it possible to return the keys of all children of a parent issue? Ideally, I'd like to return the keys for all children but not all 'grandchildren,' etc. I have the key of the parent issue as input.

edit: I can already return the keys for subtasks of a parent but I need to be able to return keys for issue children: for example, return all stories under an epic.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the python [`JIRA` library](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/), then you can achieve this via the [search_issues()](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#searching) method.

Example:

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA("my_url", basic_auth=my_auth)

parent_issue = "PR-1234"
children = jira.jql("parent=%s" % parent_issue)
```

[Read the Docs](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/jira.html#get-issues-from-jql-search-result-with-all-related-fields)

Answer (score 1):

```
from jira import JIRA
jira = JIRA("my_url", basic_auth=my_auth)

jira_object = jira_client.issue("parent-ticket")
print(jira_object.raw["fields"]["issuelinks"][0]["inwardIssue"]["key"])
```

you need to use try catch block handle keyError exception incase if that ticket doesn't have parent ticket or check if that field exists before reading the child ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a way to do this in the jira python api? I'm looking for a solution to a similar problem myself. The issues have a property of issuelinks which could be iterated.

Or you could use the following JQL to return a list of linked issues

issue in linkedIssues(ABC123)